# Wrapping Individual Text in Spans Dynamicly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem I am having seems pretty simple (and it could be maybe I am just approaching it incorrectly). I need to be able to take a users input, which could be pure text or text and HTML tags, and loop through and wrap the pure text in span tags while avoiding wrapping the html elements in span tags.

For Example, the user inputs:

```
<div>The <b>brown</b> fox <i>jumps high</i></div>
```

and the code outputs it as:

```
<div><span id='1'>The</span> <b><span id='2'>brown</span></b> <span id='3'>fox</span> <i><span id='4'>jumps</span> <span id='5'>high</span></i></div>
```

I have an idea of how to do it using Pure text, by using .text().split(" ") and then wrapping the individual results, but the HTML tags cause and issue with this method.

I don't know if this is possible or not, hopefully somebody out there has an idea of how to go about doing this effectively.

Comment: You could look at the code for [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com) and see how it does things.

Comment: `mystring.split(/(<\/?\w+(?:(?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>)/gim);` will split `<div>The <b>brown</b> fox <i>jumps high</i></div>` into `<div>, The, <b>, brown, </br> ...` and so on.